# how to delete records in dynamodb by passing a list of id's

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to delete multiple records from dynamodb.
I want to do something similar to:

```
delete * from myTable where id in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and age = 10.
```

I want to delete items matching the id's in the list I pass that also have an age equal to 10. How do I do this in Amazon dynamoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Built-in `BatchDeleteItem` batch operation can allow you to remove multiple items at once, use the following schema to enable passing a list of IDs:

```
type YourTableItem {
    id: ID!
    SomeField: String
}

type Mutation {
    batchDelete(ids: [ID]): [YourTableItem]
}

schema {
    mutation: Mutation
}
```

Next, attach a resolver to the `batchDelete()` field with the following Request Mapping Template:

```
#set($ids = [])
#foreach($id in ${ctx.args.ids})
    #set($map = {})
    $util.qr($map.put("id", $util.dynamodb.toString($id)))
    $util.qr($ids.add($map))
#end

{
    "version" : "2019-06-20",
    "operation" : "BatchDeleteItem",
    "tables" : {
        "YourTable": $util.toJson($ids)
    }
}
```

On successful configuration you can simply run the following **batchDelete** mutation:

```
mutation delete {
    batchDelete(ids:[4,7]){ id }
}
```

It will delete records with IDs 4 and 7 accordingly.

I also suggest you to read the official tutorial about DynamoDB Batch Resolvers [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html).